# Js Table of Content with anchor link does not scroll to desired tag

Tags: javascript, html, tableofcontents

I have a small JS code that detects h1 to h6 tags and provides a table of content. The problem is that clicking on a title (example title 5) simply scrolls the page to the top, while I would like it to scroll to title 5. I'm new here to JS, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

I appreciate any replies and suggestions, thanks.

---

***Edit***

Thanks to MrUpsidown's suggestion to add the ids to the h1 tags now the script works. I don't know if this is good practice, so I welcome suggestions that make the script better.

```js
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
var toc = document.createElement('div');
toc.id = 'toc';
document.body.appendChild(toc);
for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
  var heading = headings[i];
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = '#' + heading.id;
  anchor.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML;
  toc.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

```css
#toc {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#toc > a {
  padding: 10px;
}

#toc > a:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="one">Title 1</h1>
<p>Sample Text 1</p>

<h1 id="two">Title 2</h1>
<p>Sample Text 2</p>

<h1 id="three">Title 3</h1>
<p>Sample Text 3</p>

<h1 id="four">Title 4</h1>
<p>Sample Text 4</p>

<h1 id="five">Title 5</h1>
<p>Sample Text 5</p>

<h1 id="six">Title 6</h1>
<p>Sample Text 6</p>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please limit it to one problem at a time. Try to debug your code. The HTML that your script outputs are all links with `href="#"`. Provide unique IDs to your headings and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the post to focus only on the first problem. I provided the id to the tags and it works, when I click on a title it scrolls exactly where it should.

The problem is that every time I write an article I have to supply unique ids to h1 to h6 tags, it seems impractical. Can I somehow tell the script to automatically add the ids to the tags or can I achieve the result differently ?

Comment: Good for limiting your question but now it's a different question you're asking here.

Comment: Yes you would need to provide an id for each heading. You probably could do that when you build your HTML which would be easier and probably more logical than to do it with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can do this with Javascript although I'd rather try to output HTML with unique and custom ids.

In your loop, create a custom title

```
let title = 'title'+ (i+1); // Create ids of title1, title2, etc.
```

Then set the heading HTML id attribute with the computed title

```
heading.id = title; // Set heading id with title
```

Finally set the anchor href with the computed title

```
anchor.href = '#' + title; // Set href with title
```

```js
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
var toc = document.createElement('div');
toc.id = 'toc';
document.body.appendChild(toc);
for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
  var heading = headings[i];
  let title = 'title'+ (i+1); // Create ids of title1, title2, etc.
  heading.id = title; // Set heading id with title
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = '#' + title; // Set href with title
  anchor.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML;
  toc.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

```css
#toc {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#toc > a {
  padding: 10px;
}

#toc > a:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>Sample Text 1</p>

<h1>Title 2</h1>
<p>Sample Text 2</p>

<h1>Title 3</h1>
<p>Sample Text 3</p>
```